# HTMLPurifier gives error in links on live server, working properly on localhost

Tags: php, htmlpurifier

This is my code,

```
require_once 'libraries/htmlpurifier/HTMLPurifier.auto.php';
$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$purifier = new HTMLPurifier($config);

$lDesc = $_POST['long-desc'];
$lDesc = $purifier->purify($lDesc);
$lDesc = mysql_real_escape_string($lDesc);
```

if the long description have a link, the href tag converted as the following: `href="%5C"`

previously I solved this error by processing `HTMLPurifier` before `mysql_real_escape_string` and it is also still working on my localhost (inserting the real link in the href tag)
but on the live server it gives that error!

any ideas?

Comment: Every time you use [the `mysql_`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)
 database extension in new code
 **[this happens](https://media.giphy.com/media/kg9t6wEQKV7u8/giphy.gif)**
 it is deprecated and has been for years and is gone for ever in PHP7.
If you are just learning PHP, spend your energies learning the `PDO` or `mysqli` database extensions and prepared statements.
[Start here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: however your comment have no relation with my question, as you can totally skip that line and just echo the result, but in fact, it gives me the solution :D
the problem was that the server was using PHP v 5.2 I raise it to 5.4 and it is working properly now!

Answer (score 0):

The server PHP version was 5.2
I modify it to "PHP version:  5.4"
This solve that error!